# Summing Times as Durations

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to sum a time field stored in my database as an `nvarchar` like 'hh:mm', in minutes, however, the following does not work (likely because time cannot handle anything over '23:59:59'):

```
SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', MyTimeField)) AS TotalMinutes
FROM MyTable
```

Here's my [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/07ecda) on this. Any help appreciated

Comment: You can't `sum` a time. You can `sum` duration or time different between 2 time. Please show some sample data and the expected result

Comment: Your `fiddle` and the query posted in question are not in sync. Please fix it

Comment: you cannot convert `24:00` to `datetime` or `time`. It is not a valid time. There is no such time as `24:00`

Comment: Use the correct datatype i.e. `time`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's [the solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1bf0/5/0):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
    ([MyTimeField] nvarchar(5))
;
    
INSERT INTO MyTable
    ([MyTimeField])
VALUES
    ('00:15'),
    ('00:30'),
    ('01:45'),
    ('23:15'),
    ('23:59'),
    ('24:00')
;

WITH IntMinutes AS
(
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN RIGHT('0000' + MyTimeField, 5) < '24:00' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', MyTimeField)
      ELSE
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', '00:' + RIGHT(MyTimeField, 2)) +
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', CAST((LEFT(MyTimeField, 2) - 24) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':00') +
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '00:00:00', '23:59') + 1
    END AS Minutes
   FROM MyTable
 )
 
 SELECT SUM(Minutes) AS TotalMinutes
 FROM IntMinutes
```

Answer (score 0):

`24:00` is not valid, and if you try `00:00`, you have already entered the next day - but because you are not considering a full date when using `datediff`, that cannot happen. Because if you mention `00:00`, then that points at the beginning of the current day rather than the next.

Consider storing time as `datetime` rather than `varchar` - and store the clean up times as full time stamp rather than just stating the hour.